# How to reinstall AD DS for a domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

OLD SERVER: SERVER
NEW SERVER: AUTHSRV
I was playing around with my lab and I seem to have not correctly removed my old AD DS server when I added my new one so now I can't add new computers to the AD DS.

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

What direction should I go with figuring out what caused this?

I ended up deleting the old server out from under the Active Directory Sites and Services and I am not sure if that was correct or not.

EDIT:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL> ntdsutil
C:\Windows\system32\ntdsutil.exe: metadata cleanup
metadata cleanup: remove selected server SERVER
Binding to localhost ...
Connected to localhost using credentials of locally logged on user.
LDAP error 0x22(34 (Invalid DN Syntax).
Ldap extended error message is 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
        'CN=Ntds Settings,SERVER'

Win32 error returned is 0x208f(The object name has bad syntax.)
)
Unable to determine the domain hosted by the Active Directory Domain Controller (5). Please use the connection menu to s
pecify it.
```

EDIT:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL> dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = authsrv
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: CITY-HQ\AUTHSRV
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: CITY-HQ\AUTHSRV
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL
         replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.
         ......................... AUTHSRV failed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         Warning:
         CN=NTDS Settings\0ADEL:05f209fb-df38-424f-8660-52a43ce83c8e,CN=SERVER\0ADEL:fe8837d6-377c-4763-a3b8-409b2235ef9
e,CN=Servers,CN=CITY-HQ,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
         is the Schema Owner, but is deleted.
         ......................... AUTHSRV failed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... AUTHSRV passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : internal
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... internal passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... internal passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : internal.DOMAIN.com
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... internal.DOMAIN.com passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... internal.DOMAIN.com passed test Intersite
PS C:\Users\administrator.INTERNAL>
```

Comment: Either AD Sites and Services or AD Users and Computers may be used.    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your dcdiag output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a [metadata cleanup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907(v=ws.10).aspx) to remove traces of your decommissioned DC from your AD.

You should also [make sure](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mempson/archive/2007/11/08/how-to-find-out-who-has-your-fsmo-roles.aspx) all FSMO roles are held by either of your active domain controllers, [seize roles](https://abhijitw.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/fsmo-roles-transferseize-using-powershell/) if they are not.

Running a [dcdiag](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731968.aspx) could likely also provide useful info as to the overall health of your domain controllers.

*Based on your dcdiag output your deleted DC is still the Schema Owner (and probably has the other FSMO roles too).*

*You need to [forcibly seize the roles](http://www.briandesmond.com/active-directory/how-to-seize-a-fsmo-role-with-ntdsutil/), they are critical to a running AD. It is possible your metadata cleanup will then succeed.*

Comment: Question. do I need to have the old server present for the seize to work? I deleted it but I do have a .vhdx of the old that I could always boot up if needed to do a seize just curious if this can be done with the old server gone.

Comment: So just tested it. Looks like it worked. I think that powershell script actually did the fixing

Comment: Now you've done the seize you shouldn't ever boot the old DC up. There are two roles (Schema Master and RID Master) that may corrupt your AD data due to the role holder conflict.